# GNU AS symbol default type

Tags: assembly, gnu

I'm wondering what the default type GNU AS uses for symbols. The documentation for as says "If you use a symbol without defining it, as assumes zero for all these attributes" (GNU AS manual section 5.5) but it does not say what zero means for these symbols. In this case I don't care about the other attributes only type (GNU AS manual section 7.115). I assume type zero is the equivalent of "notype" but is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the default type is 'notype'. This can be found in the binutils source by looking under [binutils source directory]/include/elf/common.h. It has all the conversions for ELF executables one of which is 'notype' which is converted to zero and hence default.